# DB Migration - PostgreSQL - 30TB - OnPrem to GCP(CloudSQL)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, migration, replication, database-administration

Looking for a tool/process/procedure to migrate data from PostgreSQL 9.6 to GCP PostgreSQL(CloudSQL) 12.x.  The total data volume is 30TB (Spread across 24 PostgreSQL clusters, with 2300 DB).  We are looking at a replication mode(CloudSQL as slave) of migration(till cutover with minimal downtime) so that we can continue to function in the old site till the watermarks are same.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered offloading data as CSV in Data Lake and then mass importing using Spark + Psycopg2 COPY?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Google Database Migration API`:

here is [more information](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/reference/rest/?apix=true)

Comment: Thanks eshirvana for your response.  I suppose this requires primary key on the tables(dependency on PGLogical).  Our tables don't have any primary keys.  I should have mentioned it before, SAT.

Comment: @JPDinesh ooo that's a very bad design , add PK to your table to avoid alot of troubles